# Are classifier hyperparameters selected within cross-validation or not?

Tags: svm, hyperparameter

I was reading [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123392/grid-search-for-svm-parameters-is-this-is-really-how-it-is-done) about selecting hyper-parameters for a support vector machine classifier, where grid-search is presented as one option. Which one is correct, either

```
for f in folds
    for c in c_grid
        for s in sigma_grid
            # build svm
    # find best (c, s) pair (considering single-fold).
# find best (c, s) pair (considering all-folds)
```

or

```
for c in c_grid
    for s in sigma_grid
        for f in folds
            # build svm
# find best (c, s)
```

So does one repeat cross-validation for each (c, s) pair or does one select optimal (c, s) pair within each iteration of cross-validation?

If the first option is correct, how does one select the optimal (c,s) pair? The values could be different for different folds.

(Assume that this is the inner-loop of nested cross-validation, as per the other question.)

Answer (score 1):

In the first one, there is no guarantee that you can find a best (c,s) pair. The best (c,s) pair might be different for every fold. Use the second one.

Answer (score 1):

The correct alternative is the second one. What is missing is that the best (c,s) is the one that maximizes the **average** accuracy over the `f` folds.